# Permission denied installing libxml2

Tags: homebrew, libxml2

So I'm working on updating my rails environment to support 4.0 and ruby 2.0. So far I've had some trouble installing libxslt. When run in the terminal I get:

```
$ brew install libxml2

Error: Permission denied - /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sitecustomize.py
```

I'm running this as a root user so the permission denied message is quite puzzling. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You shouldn't install things to `/usr/local` as root or via `sudo`. From the [FAQ](https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/wiki/FAQ)

> **Why does Homebrew say sudo is bad?**
>
> Homebrew is designed to work without using sudo. You can decide to use it but we strongly recommend not to do so. ...

If you run the following, you can force the ownership of `/usr/local` in it's entirety to your logged in user

```
sudo chown -R `whoami` /usr/local
```

[Source](https://superuser.com/questions/254843/cant-install-brew-formulae-correctly-permission-denied-in-usr-local-lib)

You should no longer get `Permission Denied` issues once that's been applied.

Comment: is there any other way to resolve this issue. It will give all system permission to any login user.