# Used Homebrew to install rbenv, updated PATH, get -bash: /usr/local/bin/rbenv: Permission denied

Tags: ruby, bash, homebrew, rbenv

Installed homebrew, ran

`$ brew install rbenv ruby-build rbenv-gem-rehash
$ echo 'eval "$(rbenv init -)"' >> ~/.bash_profile
$ source ~/.bash_profile`

got `-bash: /usr/local/bin/rbenv: Permission denied`

`$ brew list` looks right, as does `$ ls /usr/local/bin`

Cannot `rbenv install 2.1.1` for same reason.

Any clues? Ta.

edit - this is my $PATH

```
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH

### Added by the Heroku Toolbelt
export PATH="/usr/local/heroku/bin:$PATH"

alias showFiles='defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles YES; killall$
alias hideFiles='defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles NO; killall $
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
eval "$(rbenv init -)"
```

Navigating using Finder, I can see no rbenv in /usr/local/bin/ - but there are aliases there for the right files, which resolve as e.g. rbenv - `/usr/local/Cellar/rbenv/0.4.0/libexec/rbenv`

I've checked this directory and the rbenv folder is there.

edit 2 - have looked at permissions /usr/local and that seems okay - i.e. have made sure I have write permission all the way down from use/local

Tried answer here - [Permission denied installing libxml2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17310942/permission-denied-installing-libxml2) - nada.

Comment: A bunch of of folk have had a look at this, but no one has responded - is this off-topic, or poorly explained? I'd be really grateful for a clue :)

Comment: haing same kind of problem but with different program.. placed in `/usr/bin` with `su` but can't call normally. Showing `Permission denied`. Please answer guys.....